# Identify object and parameterization using TestCafe automation tool

Tags: automated-testing, testcafe

I am very new to this tool. I want to learn about it and have installed the trial version but there is no option to capture an object manually.

How can I capture an object and parameterize the object properties?

Answer (score 2):

In the near future, we are going to implement data-driven testing in TestCafe that will help you resolve your issue.

To identify the object, you can use jQuery and CSS3 selectors.

Disclaimer: I work on the TestCafe team. I'd love to help you learn more about it and to hear any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As TestCafe doesn't include built-in solution to find out element locators,

---

**You can use the common element identification tools, like Chrome's [built-in Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, or [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) for Internet Explorer.**

Here's a good article on using them: **http://dailypost.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/css-selectors/**